# Is there a way to create a Spring Boot application with an embedded container which invokes remote EJBs?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb

I've gone through the Spring Boot docs but don't know if it is feasible to create a Spring Boot web application which invokes remote EJB 3.0 beans.

I don't have much experience with invoking EJBs from within Spring, but have read through Spring's [Chapter 29 Enterise EJBs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html) and it "seems" fairly straightforward.

However, is there anyway to create a Spring Boot app with an embedded container and still invoke remote EJBs?  Or do I have to deploy a war to a JEE-enabled app server (ex: JBoss, Glassfish, Websphere, etc).

Are there any gotcha's or issues I have to consider when trying to invoke remote EJB 3.0 from within a Spring Boot app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a container that provides a full Java EE implementation in order to access remote EJBs.

You can invoke a remote EJB from a simple command line program if you want.

Just follow the instructions that you linked for remote EJBs.

Note that configuration required for different target servers (where your remote EJB is hosted) can vary widely between implementations, so you will need to find out how to do it for that specific host.

You may find it easier to get a working configuration in a command line client before trying to get Spring set up because there will be less moving parts to deal with.

Comment: Any recommendations where to find the config info I need? My remote ejbs are on a Jboss 4.2.1GA host.  I thought the spring docs were a little light on that subject; I figured I needed some form of config to tell spring where to query the ejb container as well as a port number, etc

Comment: I have it working in tomcat; thanks. I'm having trouble understanding how to configure it properly in spring with annotations.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/37818227/827480.  If you have any suggestions, please let me know.