# How to define Remote EJBs Beans in Spring using annotation-based configuration (ie: JavaConfig)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb, spring-java-config

I'm trying to figure out the best way to define Remote EJB 3 beans in Spring 4.x using JavaConfig (annotation-based configuration).

I've looked at the [Spring Docs for `<jee:remote-slsb>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee-remote-slsb) and have hacked together a functional configuration, but it is terrible:

```
@Bean
public LoginManager getLoginManager(){
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean factory = new SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean();
    String beanName = "jndi.ejb3.LoginManager";
    factory.setJndiName(beanName);
    factory.setBusinessInterface(LoginManager.class);
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" );
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces" );
    p.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp:localhost:1099");
    factory.setJndiEnvironment(p);
    try {
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (NamingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (LoginManager) factory.getObject();
}
```

I shouldn't be calling `afterPropertiesSet()` in the bean definition, and I would have expected that the `getObject()` should be automatically called by Spring.  Furthermore, it also means defining the factory for every Remote EJB that I want to load, which doesn't seem right.  I would have liked/expected a way I could define a reusable factory and just pass it the Interface/JNDI name for each bean creation, but that doesn't work.

The [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-lifecycle-callbacks) indicate:

> Also, with @Bean methods, you will typically choose to use
>   programmatic JNDI lookups: either using Spring’s
>   JndiTemplate/JndiLocatorDelegate helpers or straight JNDI
>   InitialContext usage, but not the JndiObjectFactoryBean variant which
>   would force you to declare the return type as the FactoryBean type
>   instead of the actual target type, making it harder to use for
>   cross-reference calls in other @Bean methods that intend to refer to
>   the provided resource here.

So now I'm confused what to do.

The [EJB Specific spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html#ejb-access-ejb2-ejb3) also recommend using the `SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean`:

> Defining explicit `<jee:local-slsb>` / `<jee:remote-slsb>` lookups simply
>   provides consistent and more explicit EJB access configuration.

So how do I do this cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call explicity the afterProperties method since that's part of spring bean lifecycle. Additionally if you declare the bean as a factory bean, spring will automatically use the getObject to get the real object when it is needed. Here is the modified code

```
    @Bean
public FactoryBean getLoginManagerFactory(){
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean factory = new SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean();
    String beanName = "jndi.ejb3.LoginManager";
    factory.setJndiName(beanName);
    factory.setBusinessInterface(LoginManager.class);
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" );
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces" );
    p.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp:localhost:1099");
    factory.setJndiEnvironment(p);
return factory;
}
```

Comment: additionally, you can inject your properties if you want to externalise those.